# Steem Blockchain Private Network- Missing Posting Authority

Tags: blockchain

I'm trying to explore Steem Blockchain. I'm trying to set up a private testnetwork. I have the initminer account. However, when I'm trying to submit a new post, I'm getting the Missing Porting Authority.

**Request for posting blogs:**

> localhost:4000/api/v1/user/postBlog

Body

```
{   
"postTitle":"myFirstBlog",  
"postBody":"hello this is my first blog",   
"tags":"fristBlock myFrist" 
}
```

This is the request. Below is the response.

Response:

```
{
    "error": true,
    "message": "Some error in posting blog",
    "response": {
        "name": "RPCError",
        "jse_shortmsg": "Missing Posting Authority vinay001",
        "jse_info": {
            "code": 3030000,
            "name": "tx_missing_posting_auth",
            "message": "missing required posting authority",
            "stack": [
                {
                    "context": {
                        "level": "error",
                        "file": "transaction_util.hpp",
                        "line": 54,
                        "method": "verify_authority",
                        "hostname": "",
                        "timestamp": "2018-06-28T13:20:04"
                    },
                    "format": "Missing Posting Authority ${id}",
                    "data": {
                        "id": "vinay001",
                        "posting": {
                            "weight_threshold": 1,
                            "account_auths": [],
                            "key_auths": [
                                [
                                    "STM6ZJoPsL2mFdgwCSBZumbkJFMxxejxmZWqFD4qKy7Z3D41u8VrZ",
                                    1
                                ]
                            ]
                        },
                        "active": {
                            "weight_threshold": 1,
                            "account_auths": [],
                            "key_auths": [
                                [
                                    "STM5PXPWrMDhUEuxQJLUEKeuWji1YDLEZWutvyL4w45DPc81RPPyM",
                                    1
                                ]
                            ]
                        },
                        "owner": {
                            "weight_threshold": 1,
                            "account_auths": [],
                            "key_auths": [
                                [
                                    "STM8PMsuU15fwKZ68MUMMU6fTfhnBBFyEgjr7dTgafw329RZ9iqvu",
                                    1
                                ]
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "context": {
                        "level": "warn",
                        "file": "transaction_util.hpp",
                        "line": 97,
                        "method": "verify_authority",
                        "hostname": "",
                        "timestamp": "2018-06-28T13:20:04"
                    },
                    "format": "",
                    "data": {
                        "auth_containers": [
                            {
                                "type": "comment_operation",
                                "value": {
                                    "parent_author": "",
                                    "parent_permlink": "fristBlock",
                                    "author": "vinay001",
                                    "permlink": "jacx7iwp3k",
                                    "title": "myFirstBlog",
                                    "body": "hello this is my first blog",
                                    "json_metadata": "{\"tags\":[\"fristBlock\",\"myFrist\"]}"
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "sigs": [
                            "STM8486K4JZN61pa6sUgN9cZgLCnZpQrq5b4z23mdvC95wuFK6Dey"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "context": {
                        "level": "warn",
                        "file": "transaction.cpp",
                        "line": 195,
                        "method": "verify_authority",
                        "hostname": "",
                        "timestamp": "2018-06-28T13:20:04"
                    },
                    "format": "",
                    "data": {
                        "*this": {
                            "ref_block_num": 60173,
                            "ref_block_prefix": 3336246025,
                            "expiration": "2018-06-28T13:21:03",
                            "operations": [
                                {
                                    "type": "comment_operation",
                                    "value": {
                                        "parent_author": "",
                                        "parent_permlink": "fristBlock",
                                        "author": "vinay001",
                                        "permlink": "jacx7iwp3k",
                                        "title": "myFirstBlog",
                                        "body": "hello this is my first blog",
                                        "json_metadata": "{\"tags\":[\"fristBlock\",\"myFrist\"]}"
                                    }
                                }
                            ],
                            "extensions": [],
                            "signatures": [
                                "2016209a8a48f3ef7d722830a2e4d6c3e969a8c7d2caf68df636a2a51cc1ceec1314a249938913f71875db929444e549f8bcd1aea0fbddd706b3c05a7a65b83893"
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "context": {
                        "level": "warn",
                        "file": "database.cpp",
                        "line": 3208,
                        "method": "_apply_transaction",
                        "hostname": "",
                        "timestamp": "2018-06-28T13:20:04"
                    },
                    "format": "",
                    "data": {
                        "trx": {
                            "ref_block_num": 60173,
                            "ref_block_prefix": 3336246025,
                            "expiration": "2018-06-28T13:21:03",
                            "operations": [
                                {
                                    "type": "comment_operation",
                                    "value": {
                                        "parent_author": "",
                                        "parent_permlink": "fristBlock",
                                        "author": "vinay001",
                                        "permlink": "jacx7iwp3k",
                                        "title": "myFirstBlog",
                                        "body": "hello this is my first blog",
                                        "json_metadata": "{\"tags\":[\"fristBlock\",\"myFrist\"]}"
                                    }
                                }
                            ],
                            "extensions": [],
                            "signatures": [
                                "2016209a8a48f3ef7d722830a2e4d6c3e969a8c7d2caf68df636a2a51cc1ceec1314a249938913f71875db929444e549f8bcd1aea0fbddd706b3c05a7a65b83893"
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "context": {
                        "level": "warn",
                        "file": "database.cpp",
                        "line": 776,
                        "method": "push_transaction",
                        "hostname": "",
                        "timestamp": "2018-06-28T13:20:04"
                    },
                    "format": "",
                    "data": {
                        "trx": {
                            "ref_block_num": 60173,
                            "ref_block_prefix": 3336246025,
                            "expiration": "2018-06-28T13:21:03",
                            "operations": [
                                {
                                    "type": "comment_operation",
                                    "value": {
                                        "parent_author": "",
                                        "parent_permlink": "fristBlock",
                                        "author": "vinay001",
                                        "permlink": "jacx7iwp3k",
                                        "title": "myFirstBlog",
                                        "body": "hello this is my first blog",
                                        "json_metadata": "{\"tags\":[\"fristBlock\",\"myFrist\"]}"
                                    }
                                }
                            ],
                            "extensions": [],
                            "signatures": [
                                "2016209a8a48f3ef7d722830a2e4d6c3e969a8c7d2caf68df636a2a51cc1ceec1314a249938913f71875db929444e549f8bcd1aea0fbddd706b3c05a7a65b83893"
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "message": "Missing Posting Authority vinay001"
    }
}
```

Any idea why I'm having this issue. My account initminer have all the keys which I can see when I'm using get_account. However, all the keys have the same value. I'm not sure who creates these keys and when are these created. I suppose, these are created during the blockchain initiation. However, it's not mentioned clearly. Any inputs on this would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you solved it by now, but I have encountered this problem as well and found a solution.

The problem appears to be that the client you use to broadcast the transaction to your private chain still uses the default public steem chainId.

I think this has been patched for the official cli_wallet and should work by default. But I am not 100% sure about that.

If you are using a library like [dsteem](https://github.com/jnordberg/dsteem) to make a post like I do, you have to provide the chainId like this:

( Your chainId is logged in the terminal when you start your private chain )

```js
const dsteem = require('dsteem');

const client = new dsteem.Client('http://you.server.ip:port', {
  chainId: 'abc.....xyz',
});

const result = client.broadcast.comment(/* data ... */);
```

Answer (score 0):

My issue is that I was using Anaconda with beem v 0.24.21 but this version apparently has some issue. So instead of using the "conda" command, I had to use pip to install beem 0.24.26 then I stopped getting the error! I hope this helps someone, because I spent multiple days tracking this down!

```
pip install beem==0.24.26
```